# File upload issue with Django app running under Apache/mod_wsgi when daemonized

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, opera

I've got a Django app running under Apache2 (linux) using mod_wsgi and file uploads fail when running in daemon mode but works when the python interpreter is embedded.  Any idea what could be causing this and how I fix it?

The following Apache configuration is working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  Alias /media/ /var/www/media/

  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    Include /etc/apache2/yslow_optimizations.conf
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/djangoapp/apache/django.wsgi

  <Directory /var/djangoapp/apache/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I add the following directives to daemonize the wsgi process, the file upload instantly fails.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mygroup display-name=%{GROUP} inactivity-timeout=600
WSGIProcessGroup mygroup
```

There doesn't appear to be anything in the Apache error log.

The Django form is using a FileField and just gives a "this field is required" error when doing the form.is_valid().  The view has a @login_required decorator.  All of this is working fine when running in embedded mode.

Running as a daemon allows updating the code much more gracefully (by just touching the wsgi file) than when embedded which requires an Apache reload, so I'd much prefer that if it's possible.

**Update: This occurs with Opera, not with FireFox.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, you are not running latest mod_wsgi 2.X version and are using Opera browser.

There is a known issue with Opera and its use of HTTP 100-continue when using mod_wsgi daemon mode. This issue was fixed in mod_wsgi 2.4.

Since though you don't say what version of mod_wsgi you are using, nor which browser you are using, this is only a guess.

Comment: Sounds like it could have been a good guess.  I'm using Opera, didn't occur to me that it could have been a browser issue.  Looks like mod_wsgi 2.3, according to dpkg --list, from the ubuntu repository I guess.

Comment: Took a while until I could confirm by testing with FF, but you were right. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that this old friend also messes with Ajax requests (with ajax-uploader) in Firefox 10... and most likely would do the same in many other browsers.